# Creating registry key with expandable string value named (Default)?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I want to add an expanded registry entry to `HKCR\Drive\shell\Cmder\command` with a value named `(Default)`.

If I use the Registry Editor it automatically adds a string value type `REG_SZ` with the name `Default` to it. The type of the value cannot be changed or the value cannot be deleted (in order to be to be replaced with a new value) afterwards.

If I use `reg add` in command line  or a `.reg` file it says that operation completed successfully or that the keys and values have been successfully added but the registry changes are not really made.

To make sure there are no syntax errors, this is an example from [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add) that should add an expanded registry entry to `HKLM\Software\MyCo` with a value named `Path`, the type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, and data of `%systemroot%`:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\MyCo /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%systemroot^%
```

It completes successfully but again the changes in the registry are not made. The `MyCo` key is not there.

Am I possibly doing something wrong with the `reg add` command? Are there any other ways to add `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type entries with the name `(Default)` to the registry?

**UPDATE:**

The Microsoft example actually works, but in order to see the changes you need to open a new instance of the Registry Editor (the already running one won't get updated for some reason)

Comment: Did you refresh your view in `RegEdit`? From the menu bar, `View` > `Refresh`.

Comment: [Add registry values with double quotes or expandable variable data using Reg.exe](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-a-registry-value-with-double-quotes-expandable-data-using-reg-exe/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it using RegEdit. (or at least I don't think that you can!)..

Use the reg.exe command line to pull it off.
`reg.exe add <key_name> /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%path%"` (for instance).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your `reg.exe` example did exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, other ways to create a `(Default)` value of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`:

1. If you prefer creating keys/values directly in `RegEdit`, Which makes string values with embedded quotes and slashes much easier to compose, you can then let `Regedit` do the work of escaping special characters and encoding unicode strings. To create a `(Default)` value of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`:

   1. Create the key.
   2. Create a value named `temp` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` with the value you want for `(Default)`.
   3. Export to a .reg file.
   4. Edit the file, cutting `"temp"`to the clipbard then replacing with `@`. then, add a new line, pasting `"temp"` followed by `=-`.
   5. Save and merge.

[image]

Registry Export:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\DummySoftware\Path]
"temp"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,66,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,25,00,5c,00,44,00,75,00,6d,00,6d,00,79,00,53,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,\
  57,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,00,00
```

After editing:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\DummySoftware\Path]
@=hex(2):25,00,55,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,66,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,25,00,5c,00,44,00,75,00,6d,00,6d,00,79,00,53,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,\
  57,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,00,00

"temp"=-
```

After merging:
[image]

2. PowerShell is also an option.

   ```
    $Splat = @{
      'Path'     = 'HKCR:\SOFTWARE\DummySoftware2\Path'
      'Value     = '%UserProfile%\DummySoftware2'
      'ItemType' = 'ExpandString'
      'Force'    = $False
    }
    New-Item $Splat
   ```

[image]

Comment: CURSE YOU KEITH!! Your answer is so much better than mine!  I myself would use `RegSetValueEx()` with a NULL value name. :)